# How do I run a Perl program from anywhere on my computer?

Tags: perl, path, windows-7, environment-variables, strawberry-perl

I'm trying to run a Perl program - [WyD.pl](http://www.darknet.org.uk/2006/11/wyd-automated-password-profiling-tool/) - on Windows 7. I have Strawberry Perl installed, and the WyD installation folder is located at `C:\wyd.pl-0.2`.

Currently, running the program requires navigating  to the *WyD* install  directory in the command line, using `cd "C:\wyd.pl-0.2"`, and then running it with `wyd.pl`.

**How do I make it so that I can circumvent the first step entirely, and call the program with `wyd.pl` from any directory on the computer?**

Comment: Can you provide the output of the `assoc .pl` and the output `ftype NAME` (replacing `NAME` with whatever's on the RHS of `.pl=` in the ouput of `assoc .pl`).

Comment: Never mind, @ikegami - you were right with your first comment yesterday. It turned out I needed to also add `.PL` to the PATHEXT environment variable. I'd come across that solution yesterday, but didn't think it was relevant because I'd never had to do it for the command-line programs I've run in the past, but obviously I didn't think about the fact that they were contained in `.exe` files, so already existent in `PATHEXT`. Thanks for your help. If you want to put it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Re "*It turned out I needed to also add .PL to the PATHEXT environment variable*", I deleted that comment since `.PL` does not appear in my `PATHEXT` and it works on my machine.

Comment: Interesting. What paths do you have stored in PATH? Also, do you use Strawberry Perl or another Perl distribution?

Comment: The relevant path in `PATH` is `C:\wyd`. /// ActivePerl, but this has nothing to do with who built my Perl; this is all the OS.

Comment: Okay, I just tested again, and it appears that I was probably getting confused between the two things I was trying to do. To clarify: having the paths set in the *PATH* envrironment variable allows me to call the program from anywhere on my computer using `wyd.pl`, which was the main focus of this question. At the same time, I was also trying to make it so that I could call with just `wyd` i.e., without the extension, which is what including the extension *.PL* in the *EXT* environment variable does. To confirm - are you able to call the program with `wyd` alone, *without* changing *EXT*?

Comment: No, used `wyd.pl`. `PATHEXT` is what allows you to omit the extension.

Comment: Pretty much confirms that, then. Just me being vacant-minded. I'm kinda embarassed to even write an answer now, lol.

Comment: Your question would request a rewrite to be useful, so you could simply delete it instead.

Comment: I'm considering rewriting it. Do you think it's likely to be flagged as duplicate if I do?

Comment: Depends in which direction you change it. I don't know either way, though.

Comment: I may as well go for it, unless you'd rather write it instead? I appreciate that you've spent a lot of time helping me, and if anyone should get the reputation for the simple answer that remains, it should be you. If you'd rather not, I'd be happy to.